# Wait until a task is finished in parse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to parse and was wondering if there was a built in way to wait for a task to finish before continuing to the next statement. I have accomplished this with a workaround but would like to do it properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code.

```
public IEnumerator CreateNewPet(int type)
{
    bool canContinue = false; /*this is the boolean that stops the script from moving forward until parse has finished */
    gcMenuController.LoadingOn();
    Texture2D photo = GameObject.Find("PetPicture").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture as Texture2D;
    imageData = photo.EncodeToPNG();
    byte[] data = imageData;

    ParseObject petInfo = new ParseObject("Pet");
    petInfo["user"] = ParseUser.CurrentUser;
    petInfo["petType"] = type;
    petInfo["petName"] = gcMenuController.createName;
    petInfo["dateOfBirth"] = DateTime.Parse(gcMenuController.createBirthday);
    petInfo["petBio"] = gcMenuController.createBio;
    Task savePetTask = petInfo.SaveAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
        petID2 = petInfo.ObjectId;
        canContinue = true;
    });
    while (!canContinue)
    { /*This while loop waits until the canContinue bool has been set to true before moving forward */
        yield return null;
    }

    ParseFile file = new ParseFile(gcMenuController.createName + ".png", data);
    Task saveTask = file.SaveAsync();
    ParseObject point = ParseObject.CreateWithoutData("Pet", petID2);
    var picture = new ParseObject("Photo");
    picture["imageFile"] = file;
    picture["user"] = ParseUser.CurrentUser;
    picture["pet"] = point;
    Task saveTask2 = picture.SaveAsync();
    print("ParseController.AddPetPhoto() - Photo uploaded under petID2 " + petID2);
    gcMenuController.StartCoroutine("LoadingOff");


    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: Since it's Unity I guess you can't await. How about putting all of the code into the continuation? Or do you have to know in the caller when this finishes?

Comment: I can put the lower part of the parse code into a continuation but i need the gcMenuController.StartCoroutine("LoadingOff") to wait for parse to finish before running and it can only be run the the main thread because it is a coroutine.

Comment: Lol thank you though i don't know why i didn't do that to begin with. You have already made it better...

Comment: The `Task` class is not available for use in Unity3D due to the latter's ceiling of .NET 3.5